# A bit of confusion with the differentiation of convolution and support of functions

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be compactly supported smooth functions. Especially, let us suppose that their supports are both contained in $[0,\infty)$.

Then, I see that we may write their convolution as
\begin{equation}
(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y)dy=\int^x_0 f(y)g(x-y)dy
\end{equation}

Now, it is well-known that $(f*g)'=f'*g=f*g'$. However, according to the far right-hand side of the above definition for $(f*g)(x)$ the domain of integration itself contains $x$.

So, I think we have to apply the Leibniz rule for integrals to take $\int^x_0$ into account.

However, the middle formula  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y)dy$ does NOT contain any $x$ in the doamin of integration.

This is quite confusing for me....Could anyone please clarfiy?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Leibniz formula to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y)dy$ gives:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)g'(x-y)dy$$

This can be rewritten as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)g'(x-y)dy&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^{t}f(y)g'(x-y)dy\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{t}f(y)g'(x-y)dy\qquad \text{(since $f(y)=0$ for $y\leq 0$)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)g'(x-y)dy+\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{x}^{t}f(y)g'(x-y)dy
\end{align*}$$

And, using integration by parts, we have for $t>x$:

$$\begin{align*}\int_{x}^{t}f(y)g'(x-y)dy&=[-f(y)g(x-y)]_x^t+\int_{x}^{t}f'(y)g(x-y)dy\\
&=f(x)g(0)-f(t)g(x-t)+\int_{x}^{t}f'(y)g(x-y)dy\\
&=f(x)g(0)\qquad \text{(since $g(s)=0$ for $s<0$)}
\end{align*}$$

Thus we get

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)g'(x-y)dy=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)g'(x-y)dy+f(x)g(0)
\end{align*}$$

---

Applying the Leibniz formula to the integral $\int^x_0 f(y)g(x-y)dy$ gives the same expression:

$$f(x)g(0)+\int_0^xf(y)g'(x-y)dy$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by limits of integration??

Comment: One of my formula for the convolution has the domain of integration as only $[0,x]$.

Comment: The middle formula has an improper integral with limits $-\infty $ and $+\infty$. Leibniz rule can only be applied when the limits are continuous and differentiable functions of the parameter you want to differentiate with respect to ($x$ here). You can apply Leibniz rule to the integral on the right, but not the left one.

Comment: Yes, my question is that, if I apply the Leibniz formula to the right one, do I still get the same result as the middle one? This seems nontrivial.

Comment: You cannot apply the Leibniz rule to the left integral. It is only once it is transformed to the right integral that you can apply the rule.

Comment: Not true. With sufficient decay assumptions you can apply Leibniz’s rule, and with $f,g$ being smooth compactly supported, everything is super nice and you can apply Leibniz’s rule repeatedly. And @Keith, did you try working out the derivatives of the two expressions? What do you get? They should obviously be equal.

Comment: Sorry, although, in general, you cannot apply the Leibniz rule in the case where the limits are infinite, you are right that it works here. I have now updated my answer to show that applying the formula to either integral gives the same answer.